# Commutator of Hamiltonian and time-reversal operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, time-reversal-symmetry

How can I show that the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ and time-reversal operator $\hat{T}:t \mapsto -t$ commute, i.e. that $$[\hat{H},\hat{T}] = \hat{H}\hat{T} - \hat{T}\hat{H} = 0$$ holds?

Comment: This is not true in general but depends on the form of the Hamiltonian

Comment: If the Hamiltonian is given by $\hat{H} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$, is it possible now to check if $\hat{H}$ and $\hat{T}$ are commuting?

Comment: I personally know the time reversal operator from QFT, where it makes sense because a quantum field depends on space and time. The wavefunctions in typical QM only depend on position (and mabye some internal parameters like spin). Time is only a label which comes from "outside". In that situation I don't see how time reversal makes sense. Could you clarify that? Maybe you have a specific situation in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you define time reversal algebraically. In the case of QM, it is by:
$$
\begin{align}
TxT^{-1} &= x & TpT^{-1} &= -p
\end{align}
$$
Which is the same as in classical Hamiltonian mechanics. For it to preserve the CAR’s, $T$ needs to be antiunitary.

From there, assuming that the Hamiltonian is algebraic in $x,p$, it’s the same argument as for the classical case. The Hamiltonian transforms as:
$$
TH(x,p)T^{-1}=H(x,-p)^*
$$
So you just need to check that the latter expression is still the original Hamiltonian. The asterisk means that you need to take complex conjugate of any complex scalars involved in the expression (this is not the same as taking the hermitian conjugate, which would additionally change the order).

In your example:
$$
H=\frac{p^2}{2}
$$
which is invariant by time reversal. In general, any Hamiltonian of the form:
$$
H(x,p)=f(x,p^2)
$$
with $f$ only involving real numbers obeys time reversal symmetry.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Helps a lot.